# DOMStringMap values to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dataset

How can i create array of values from dataset? I'm looking for answer everywhere and i can't find anything.

I have 6 img elements i HTML with dataset (there are informations about what is at picture), i've created variable with dataset of all img elements like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
        let allDataset1 = [];
        allDataset1.push(allImages[i].dataset);
        console.log(allDataset1);
```

Console shows me DOMStringMap with values of dataset and now i need to create an array of this values, or maybe i don't need.. I have to compare user input text to each value of dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the find method on the allDataset1 array to compare the user input text value and check whether the user input matches any values in the allDataset1 array.

The find() method on the array returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function

Assuming the userInput variable has the userInput value stored in it,all you have to do is the following.

```
const datasetEnteredByUser = allDataset1.find((val) => val === userInput).
```

datasetEnteredByUser will be undefined if no value in the allDataset1 matches the userInput.

Based upon the discussion in the comments below, allDataset1 is an array of img elements and  you have a comma seperated string in the dataset attribute for every img element.

So, i think you would need to create the allDataset1 in the following manner before comparing it with the user input.

```
let allDataset1 = []
[...allImages].forEach(img => { // Converting the allImages  array of Dom elements into a Javascript array to iterate on.
    allDataset1 = allDataset1.concat(img.getAttribute('dataset').split(','))
})
```

You can then the find method on allDataset1 to compare every element in the string with the user input.

Comment: Ok, i understand but my allDataset1 is not array of values. I need to get values of dataset and push it into array and then compare values to user input

Comment: Can you provide an example as to how allDataset1 will finally look like.I am under the impression that it's an array of strings.But if it is more complex than that , could you provide like the  output of console.log(allDataset1)

Comment: I have 6 images with dataset, each img has got different dataset (1st img dataset (bike, people), 2nd img dataset(night, car, people) etc.) and i want to compare all this dataset strings to user input. So i need to create array, take values of dataset and push it into this array to create a for loop and compare input and this strings. Console.log(allDataset1) shows me: [DOMStringMap]
0: DOMStringMap {tag: "baseball,sport,people"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0) etc.
allDataset1 should looks like allDataset1 = [bike, baseball, sport, people, night etc.]

Comment: Got it, just updated the answer based upon your explanation.